# Wrong version of libcublas used

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I have cuda-9.0 installed, and in the /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 library, there exists shared file `libcublas.so.9.0`. However, whenever I do `locate libcublas`, I get the following:

```
locate libcublas
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.7.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.7.5.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas_device.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas_static.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs/libcublas.so
/usr/share/doc/libcublas7.5
/usr/share/doc/libcublas7.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcublas7.5/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcublas7.5
/usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.7.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.so.7.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcublas7.5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcublas7.5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcublas7.5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcublas7.5:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcublas7.5:amd64.triggers
```

And when I do `whereis libcublas` I get:

```
libcublas: /usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.7 
           /usr/share/man/man7/libcublas.7.gz
```

In my `~/.bashrc` file, I have the following:

```
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-9.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

This is causing problems for tensorflow when I want to use RunMetaData. Please help, any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an old CUDA 7.5 install.  You should remove it.  This is also incorrect: `export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH"`  Your quotes are misplaced.  It should be: `export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin":$PATH`.  It's also not really clear to me that you ahve CUDA 9.0 installed correctly, but your claim it is.  It may be.

Comment: Nit: The quotes are fine. In fact your variant will fail if PATH has an entry with a whitespace in it. That said, you are probably right that it's the old CUDA package that messes things up. I suspect it's the *headers* that actually get in the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

I installed 4 `libcublas` patches for `CUDA 9.0`.

In the .bashrc file, I got rid of the quotations. 
Instead of `export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH"` I used `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:$PATH`

Then I restarted all the terminals.